# For a lay person, what if there was no atmosphere?

Tags: atmospheric-science, air, relative-motion

What if there was no atmosphere (or little like on the moon)? Could I then hover above and watch the Earth below turn?

Originally I queried, "why couldn't a person just float up in a balloon, hover above, and watch the earth below rotate?" In my own ignorance, I didn't think of the air I can't see as having mass effects. It was explained to me that the atmosphere is moving along with the earth. So I hadn't presumed the air i.e. atmosphere, I'm floating in would be rotating along with the earth at the same speed. Hence I asked, "what if there was no (or minimal as on the moon) atmosphere?" Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i understand your question, but correct me if I'm wrong:
You want to know why, for example, a balloon "follows" the rotation of the earth, even if it's not touching the ground. In your mind, since the balloon is floating, it shouldn't be "moved" by the earth, and so you could watch the earth spin while in the balloon.

The answer is: Even without an atmosphere, you still couldn't do it. When the balloon is grounded, you have a horizontal movement - you are at the same speed as the earth. Of course you don't notice it because there is no acceleration, so you don't feel any "force", but the earth is rotating at an enormous speed.

When you take off, you are obtaining vertical velocity. However, this does not influence your original horizontal velocity. If you want to think of it another way, think about a person in a giant treadmill wearing a jetpack. He's going to the left, and then he activates the jetpack. Disconsidering air resistance, he would keep going to the left, because he still has that horizontal speed.

I hope this helps you understand. If it's still unclear to you i'd recommend you to read on conservation of momentum and relative momentum.